# OSX 10.8 trying to browse website hosted on remote machine connected by VPN

Tags: macos, vpn, browser, hosts

I have a development version of my website `my.sandbox` running on my work computer. (Ubuntu).

I have a VPN connection from my home computer (OSX 10.8) to my work computer which works successfully.

I have added the following line to the `/etc/hosts` on my home computer:

```
nnn.nn.nn.nn        my.sandbox
```

where nnn.nn.nn.nn is the IP address of my work computer.

I have cleared my browser cache and I have rebooted my home OSX machine (I know you shouldn't have to, but…).

BUT, when I browse to http://my.sandbox I see the version of `my.sandbox` which is running on my local OSX machine. There used to be a line

```
127.0.0.1            my.sandbox
```

in my `/etc/hosts` file, but I've removed it. So why is it still mapping `my.sandbox` to my local machine, rather than the remote one?

Any advice gratefully received.

**UPDATE - PROBLEM HAS MAGICALLY FIXED ITSELF**

I don't know what's happened, but `http://my.sandbox` is now directing me to the work version of my website. Many thanks to everyone for your helpful suggestions, and apologies that I can't tell you how this has been fixed.

Comment: Have you rebooted since erasing the line from /etc/hosts? And what happens if you `ping my.sandbox`?

Comment: Yes thanks, but still seeing the same behaviour :-(

Comment: most likely you where getting a cached answer and flushing the cache solved it.

Answer (score 0):

What about flushing DNS?

`sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202516

Comment: Tried that too … no luck

Comment: Is the correct website visible if you do `nn.nn.nn.nn:port` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try if `nslookup my.sandbox` is giving you a cached answer. Flushing the DNS Cache might help in that case.

How to do this depends on the version of OSX you use.

OS X Yosemite 10.10.4 use the following command in your terminal:
`sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`

OS X Yosemite 10.10 to 10.10.3 use
`sudo discoveryutil mdnsflushcache`

OS X Mavericks, Mountain Lion und Lion use:
`sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`

Mac OS X 10.6 use 
`sudo dscacheutil -flushcache`

Comment: User told you he's running 10.8